# Linq, use "variable" inside a anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to accomplish something like this,

```
var data = from p in db.Projects
                   select new
                   {
                       Cost = p.CostReports.FirstOrDefault().Charged,
                       Tax = Cost * 0.25
                   };
```

In other words, I want to use Cost as a variable. Is it possible? If so, how?

My code is just an example, the project I'm working on is a bit more complicated.

Edit:

I hope this is a better example of what I'm trying to do,

```
var data = (from p in db.Projects
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = p.ProjectName,
                        Customer = p.CustomerID,
                        Cost = p.Cost
                    }).GroupBy(p => p.Customer)
                   .Select(g => new
                   {
                       Something = g.Where(p => p.Customer == g.Key).Sum(p => p.Cost),
                       SomethingElse = Something * 0.25
                   });
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the `let` keyword in your query.

```
var data = from p in db.Projects 
           let cost = p.CostReports.FirstOrDefault().Charged
           select new 
           { 
              Cost = cost,
              Tax = cost * 0.25 
           };
```

**Edit**

Regarding your update and barring additional information, I might still be tempted to use `let` by rewriting your query structure.

```
var data = from g in db.Projects.Select(p => 
                new
                {
                    Name = p.ProjectName,
                    Customer = p.CustomerID,
                    Cost = p.Cost
                }
            ).GroupBy(p => p.Customer)
            let something = g.Sum(p => p.Cost)
            select new
            {
                Something = something,
                SomethingElse = something * 0.25
            };
```

In this case, `from g in ...` refers to the grouped data, which allows you to use query expression syntax against this data, including `let`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess my example was a bit to simple. I know about "let". Please see my edit above..

Comment: Thanks, didn't know I could use let there. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var data = from p in db.Projects
           let cost = p.CostReports.FirstOrDefault().Charged
           select new
           {
               Cost = cost,
               Tax = cost * 0.25
           };
```

Answer (score 2):

You could at least chain selects together and store your anonymous type as an intermediate result:

```
var data = (from p in db.Projects
               select new
               {
                   Cost = p.CostReports.FirstOrDefault().Charged,
                   Tax = Cost * 0.25
               })
           .select(anon => new { Cost = anon.Cost, Tax = anon.Cost * 0.25 });
```

Comment: Ain't nothing wrong with this approach. This is effectively what a let statement boils down to.